# How can I schedule a program to run whenever after iis recycle?

Tags: iis, schedule, recycle

I need to run a program that warm up my app. Is there some way to schedule that whenever iis recycle?

I'm using IIS 7.5.

Comment: You can schedule a task that listens for an event, assuming IIS does log events when it recycles the app-pool

Comment: Thanks, I did something similar to that using a event listener: http://dotnetspeak.com/2014/01/detecting-app-pool-recycling-and-mitigating-its-effects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a batchfile or exe that does the warming up you can schedule it as follows for a manual `issreset`

execute on ONE single line on a commandprompt:

```
schtasks /create 
         /tn warmup-app 
         /tr drive:\path\warmup.cmd 
         /sc ONEVENT 
         /EC System
         /MO *[System/EventID=3201]
```

and if executed you're greeted with

> SUCCESS: The scheduled task "warmup-app" has successfully been created.

Now configure IIS to log it's apppool restarts in the EventLog:

[image]